# Case matching pattern replacement with sed

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have a source code spread across several files.

- It has a pattern `abcdef` which I need to replace with `pqrstuvxyz`.
- The pattern could be `Abcdef` (Sentence Case) then it needs to be replaced with `Pqrstuvxyz`.
- The pattern could be `AbCdEf` (Toggle case) then it needs to be replaced with `PqRsTuVxYz`.

In short, I need to match the case of the source pattern and apply the appropriate destination pattern.

How can I achieve this using `sed` or any other tool?

Comment: And if it's `ABcDeF`?

Comment: PQrStUvxyz  - I get your point.

Comment: So if `ABcDeF` -> `PQrStUvxyz`, then surely `AbCdEf` -> `PqRsTuvxyz` would be logically consistent. If the case is to be copied from one string to the other, what should happen if the second replacement string is longer.

Comment: Well lets trim the replacement to "pqrstu" for the sake of brevity.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Portable solution using `sed`:

```
sed '
:1
/[aA][bB][cC][dD][eE][fF]/!b
s//\
&\
pqrstu\
PQRSTU\
/;:2
s/\n[[:lower:]]\(.*\n\)\(.\)\(.*\n\).\(.*\n\)/\2\
\1\3\4/;s/\n[^[:lower:]]\(.*\n\).\(.*\n\)\(.\)\(.*\n\)/\3\
\1\2\4/;t2
s/\n.*\n//;b1'
```

It's a bit easier with GNU sed:

```
search=abcdef replace=pqrstuvwx
sed -r ":1;/$search/I!b;s//\n&&&\n$replace\n/;:2
    s/\n[[:lower:]](.*\n)(.)(.*\n)/\l\2\n\1\3/
    s/\n[^[:lower:]](.*\n)(.)(.*\n)/\u\2\n\1\3/;t2
    s/\n.*\n(.*)\n/\1/g;b1"
```

By using `&&&` above, we reuse the case pattern of the string for the rest of the replacement, So `ABcdef` would be changed to `PQrstuVWx` and `AbCdEf` to `PqRsTuVwX`.
Change it to `&` to affect only the case of the first 6 characters.

(note that it may not do what you want or may run into an infinite loop if the replacement may be subject to substitution (for instance if substituting `foo` for `foo`, or `bcd` for `abcd`)

Answer (score 8):

Portable solution using `awk`:

```
awk -v find=abcdef -v rep=pqrstu '{
  lwr=tolower($0)
  offset=index(lwr, tolower(find))

  if( offset > 0 ) {
    printf "%s", substr($0, 0, offset)
    len=length(find)

    for( i=0; i<len; i++ ) {
      out=substr(rep, i+1, 1)

      if( substr($0, offset+i, 1) == substr(lwr, offset+i, 1) )
        printf "%s", tolower(out)
      else
        printf "%s", toupper(out)
    }

    printf "%s\n", substr($0, offset+len)
  }
}'
```

Example input:

```
other abcdef other
other Abcdef other
other AbCdEf other
```

Example output:

```
other pqrstu other
other Pqrstu other
other PqRsTu other
```

#### Update

As pointed out in the comments, the above will only replace the first instance of `find` in every line. To replace all instances:

```
awk -v find=abcdef -v rep=pqrstu '{
  input=$0
  lwr=tolower(input)
  offset=index(lwr, tolower(find))

  if( offset > 0 ) {
    while( offset > 0 ) {

      printf "%s", substr(input, 0, offset)
      len=length(find)

      for( i=0; i<len; i++ ) {
        out=substr(rep, i+1, 1)

        if( substr(input, offset+i, 1) == substr(lwr, offset+i, 1) )
          printf "%s", tolower(out)
        else
          printf "%s", toupper(out)
      }

      input=substr(input, offset+len)
      lwr=substr(lwr, offset+len)
      offset=index(lwr, tolower(find))
    }

    print input
  }
}'
```

Example input:

```
other abcdef other ABCdef other
other Abcdef other abcDEF
other AbCdEf other aBCdEf other
```

Example output:

```
other pqrstu other PQRstu other
other Pqrstu other pqrSTU
other PqRsTu other pQRsTu other
```

Comment: Note that is only processes one instance per line.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas, updated to handle multiple instances.

Answer (score 6):

You could use `perl`.  Straight from the faq -- quoting from `perldoc perlfaq6`:

**How do I substitute case-insensitively on the LHS while preserving case on the RHS?**

Here's a lovely Perlish solution by Larry Rosler. It exploits
       properties of bitwise xor on ASCII strings.

```
   $_= "this is a TEsT case";

   $old = 'test';
   $new = 'success';

   s{(\Q$old\E)}
   { uc $new | (uc $1 ^ $1) .
           (uc(substr $1, -1) ^ substr $1, -1) x
           (length($new) - length $1)
   }egi;

   print;
```

And here it is as a subroutine, modeled after the above:

```
       sub preserve_case($$) {
               my ($old, $new) = @_;
               my $mask = uc $old ^ $old;

               uc $new | $mask .
                       substr($mask, -1) x (length($new) - length($old))
   }

       $string = "this is a TEsT case";
       $string =~ s/(test)/preserve_case($1, "success")/egi;
       print "$string\n";
```

This prints:

```
           this is a SUcCESS case
```

As an alternative, to keep the case of the replacement word if it is
       longer than the original, you can use this code, by Jeff Pinyan:

```
   sub preserve_case {
           my ($from, $to) = @_;
           my ($lf, $lt) = map length, @_;

           if ($lt < $lf) { $from = substr $from, 0, $lt }
           else { $from .= substr $to, $lf }

           return uc $to | ($from ^ uc $from);
           }
```

This changes the sentence to "this is a SUcCess case."

Just to show that C programmers can write C in any programming
       language, if you prefer a more C-like solution, the following script
       makes the substitution have the same case, letter by letter, as the
       original.  (It also happens to run about 240% slower than the Perlish
       solution runs.)  If the substitution has more characters than the
       string being substituted, the case of the last character is used for
       the rest of the substitution.

```
   # Original by Nathan Torkington, massaged by Jeffrey Friedl
   #
   sub preserve_case($$)
   {
           my ($old, $new) = @_;
           my ($state) = 0; # 0 = no change; 1 = lc; 2 = uc
           my ($i, $oldlen, $newlen, $c) = (0, length($old), length($new));
           my ($len) = $oldlen < $newlen ? $oldlen : $newlen;

           for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
                   if ($c = substr($old, $i, 1), $c =~ /[\W\d_]/) {
                           $state = 0;
                   } elsif (lc $c eq $c) {
                           substr($new, $i, 1) = lc(substr($new, $i, 1));
                           $state = 1;
                   } else {
                           substr($new, $i, 1) = uc(substr($new, $i, 1));
                           $state = 2;
                   }
           }
           # finish up with any remaining new (for when new is longer than old)
           if ($newlen > $oldlen) {
                   if ($state == 1) {
                           substr($new, $oldlen) = lc(substr($new, $oldlen));
                   } elsif ($state == 2) {
                           substr($new, $oldlen) = uc(substr($new, $oldlen));
                   }
           }
           return $new;
   }
```

Comment: Note that it's limited to ASCII letters.

Answer (score 5):

If you trim the replace to `pqrstu`, try this:

Input:

```
abcdef
Abcdef
AbCdEf
ABcDeF
```

Ouput:

```
$ perl -lpe 's/$_/$_^lc($_)^"pqrstu"/ei' file
pqrstu
Pqrstu
PqRsTu
PQrStU
```

If you want replace with `prstuvxyz`, may be this:

```
$ perl -lne '@c=unpack("(A4)*",$_);
    $_ =~ s/$_/$_^lc($_)^"pqrstu"/ei;
    $c[0] =~ s/$c[0]/$c[0]^lc($c[0])^"vxyz"/ei;
    print $_,$c[0]' file
pqrstuvxyz
PqrstuVxyz
PqRsTuVxYz
PQrStUVXyZ
```

I can not find any rule to map `ABcDeF` -> `PQrStUvxyz`.

Comment: Note that it's limited to ASCII letters.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this would do what you described.

```
sed -i.bak -e "s/abcdef/pqrstuvxyz/g" \
 -e "s/AbCdEf/PqRsTuVxYz/g" \
 -e "s/Abcdef/Pqrstuvxyz/g" files/src
```